# Status filter is not working in admin

Tags: product, magento2.3, filter

We are using **Magento2.3** and found an issue that is status filter is not working properly in admin.

We have some of the products which is disabled. When I filter the product with Status disabled, I'm also getting the products which is enabled.

[image]

Did anyone find the same issue?

Could anyone please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you will select a store view you instead of "All store views" you'll notice that it will be working correctly. Is it Magento 2.3.2?

According to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23435 "The issue has been fixed in #23444 by @mattijv in 2.3-develop branch
Related commit(s):

4adee3b19c1396251d29c54df3eb874d5c985388 "
The fix will be available with the upcoming 2.3.3 release.

Basically you'll need to override app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/ProductCollection.php and incorporate the fix from https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/4adee3b19c1396251d29c54df3eb874d5c985388

Comment: Yes, it's Magento 2.3.2

Comment: According to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23435 "The issue has been fixed in #23444 by @mattijv in 2.3-develop branch
Related commit(s):

4adee3b19c1396251d29c54df3eb874d5c985388 "
The fix will be available with the upcoming 2.3.3 release.

Comment: Well if it was fixed in 2.3.3 then it seems the fix was somehow lost by the time 2.3.5 came around. I've replicated the bug in 2.3.5, 2.3.5-p1 and 2.4.0. :( (I don't have a 2.3.3 installation to try it on, unfortunately)